# Как скачать вложение с русским именем?

Tags: php, imap

Как скачать вложение с кириллицей в имени?

У меня есть такой код, но я получаю ошибку, когда имя на русском:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php

set_time_limit(3000);

$hostname = '{imap.ukr.net:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = ''; # например somebody@gmail.com
$password = '';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
$max_emails = 16;

if($emails) {

    $count = 1;
     rsort($emails);
     foreach($emails as $email_number)
    {

        /* get information specific to this email */                
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

        /* get mail message */
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* get mail structure */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts))
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++)
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters)
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object)
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename')
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters)
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object)
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name')
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment'])
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3)

                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */   
                 elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4)
                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    } 
                }
        }
        }

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                $filename = $attachment['name'];
            if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . "dat";

                /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                 * have the attachment with the same file name.
                 */
     $fp = fopen('/mnt/c/1/'. $filename, "w+");
             fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);
            }

        }

        if($count++ >= $max_emails) break;
    }

}


imap_close($inbox);

echo "Done";

?>
```

Comment: Тут говорят по-русски.

Answer (score 0):

Буду краток

- http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php
- `idn_to_ascii('вася.txt');`